# How to call angular js controller from another controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How to call  web service  with AngularJS on checkbox change event.
here is my code

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('checkBoxCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 

    $scope.SelectedMobileCateg = function () {
        alert($scope.SelectedMobID);
        debugger;
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:50622/api/GetMobile/getMobiles').
              success(function (data) {
                  $scope.products = data;
                  debugger;
              }).
              error(function (data) {
                  debugger;
                  alert("erro");
              });
        });
    };

}]);
```

I will be very thanks full to you

Comment: Wow wow wow, why do you have a controller only for a checkbox in the first place ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? It's not maybe the good solution

Comment: @Alburkerk covered it pretty well in his answer, so I just have a side note: Using `success` and `error` on the $http service is deprecated since they don't return a promise and thus doesn't chain. Use `then` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to learn more about Angular structure first..

Take a look at John Papa guidelines (easy to find), to learn what should be a controller or not.

Controller are made to be associated with a view / state, ie a big component. So it is very unlikely to be associated with only a checkbox (because it's only a boolean after all).

It you only need to call an http request from multiple endpoints, take a look at what services or factory are for. Just define your http request in a factory, and call it from multiple controllers.

If you really need to spend messages between different controllers, which is unlikely to be the case with your description of your problem, you can use $scope documentation and search about $scope.emit, $scope.broadcast etc..

Here's an [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/wq5q4i/) of their use. But as I said, learn more first.